# Infragistics Jquery Tree

Tags: jquery-ui, infragistics

I need some help from you in using igTree when LoadOnDemand is set to true.
I have a WCF REST Service which is giving me data to populate in igTree.

Please find the sample code..

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "AssessmentProcWCFService.svc/GetAllEntities",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{}',
                cache: false,
                success: OnGetAllEntitiesSuccess,
                error: OnGetAllEntitiesFailure
            });
```

==================================================

```
function OnGetAllEntitiesSuccess(categoryList) {
   $("#APTreeView").igTree({
                    animationDuration: 0,
                    dataSourceType: 'json',
                    dataSource: categoryList.d,
                    initialExpandDepth: false,
                    loadOnDemand: true,
                    dataSourceUrl: "AssessmentProcWCFService.svc/GetAllCategories?EntityID=primaryKey:id",
                    bindings: {
                        textKey: 'text',
                        valueKey: 'id',
                        primaryKey: 'id',
                        expanded: 'expanded',
                        childDataProperty: 'children'
                    }
                });
            }
```

=========================================================

Questions:-

1. How could I send the selected node ID to the Service when any node of the tree is expanding?
   The way I am sending in the above example it is not working when I am retrieving it in the service “public List GetAllCategories()” like 
   “string entityID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["EntityID"];”
   I am getting entity id as null.
2. How the tree get rendered when any node get expanded if LoadOnDemand is true?

Please help me on this I have spend lot of time in it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can encode anything you like in the request made to the service:

Here are the default request parameters explained: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/65356.aspx

And here is how you can add a request parameter:

```
function OnGetAllEntitiesSuccess(categoryList) {
   $("#APTreeView").igTree({
                    animationDuration: 0,
                    dataSourceType: 'json',
                    dataSource: categoryList.d,
                    initialExpandDepth: false,
                    loadOnDemand: true,
                    dataSourceUrl: "AssessmentProcWCFService.svc/GetAllCategories?EntityID=primaryKey:id",
                    bindings: {
                        textKey: 'text',
                        valueKey: 'id',
                        primaryKey: 'id',
                        expanded: 'expanded',
                        childDataProperty: 'children'
                    },
                    nodePopulating: function (event, ui) {
                        var node = '&SelectedNodeID=' + $("#APTreeView").igTree('selectedNode').element.attr('data-value'),
                            myNewUrl = 'AssessmentProcWCFService.svc/GetAllCategories?EntityID=primaryKey:id' + node;
                        $('#myTree').igTree('option', 'dataSourceUrl', myNewUrl);
                    }
                });
            }
```